# Repeat Orders + Order Count and Total for Each

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I was asked to find people who bought between June - August 2012 and again in September - October 2012. So I did that. This query got results for me that looked right when I checked them out.

```
SELECT o.BillEmail
FROM dbo.tblOrder o
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(o2.OrderDate) 
    FROM dbo.tblOrder o2 
    WHERE o2.OrderID = o.OrderID 
        AND o2.OrderDate >= '2012-06-01' AND o2.OrderDate <= '2012-08-31') > 0 
        AND (SELECT COUNT(o2.OrderDate)
            FROM dbo.tblOrder o2 
                WHERE o2.BillEmail = o.BillEmail 
                    AND o2.OrderDate >= '2012-09-01' AND o2.OrderDate <= '2012-10-31'
                    AND o2.DomainProjectID=13) > 0
    GROUP BY o.BillEmail
    ORDER BY o.BillEmail
```

Then they asked me to find the total orders placed by each customer during those two time periods, and how much those orders all totaled to be. So I just added those requirements:

```
SELECT o.BillEmail, COUNT(o.OrderID) as Orders, SUM(o.Total) as 'Total'
FROM dbo.tblOrder o
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(o2.OrderDate) 
    FROM dbo.tblOrder o2 
    WHERE o2.OrderID = o.OrderID 
        AND o2.OrderDate >= '2012-06-01' AND o2.OrderDate <= '2012-08-31') > 0 
        AND (SELECT COUNT(o2.OrderDate)
            FROM dbo.tblOrder o2 
            WHERE o2.BillEmail = o.BillEmail 
                AND o2.OrderDate >= '2012-09-01' AND o2.OrderDate <= '2012-10-31'
                AND o2.DomainProjectID=13) > 0
    GROUP BY o.BillEmail
    ORDER BY o.BillEmail
```

However this only pulls orders from the first specified time period of June to August. So it's only showing orders and totals spent from then and not the second half as well.

How do I get it to pull both period's data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your query it seems you are only interested in DomainProjectID = 13, right? Also, if the OrderDate is a datetime and has some time values (ie. '2012-10-31 00:00:00.001' which is greater than '2012-10-31') then some results might be excluded.

With that said, here's one way to get that information:

```
Select
    o.BillEmail,
    SUM(CASE WHEN o.OrderDate >= '2012-06-01' and o.OrderDate < '2012-09-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as JunToAugOrders,
    SUM(CASE WHEN o.OrderDate >= '2012-06-01' and o.OrderDate < '2012-09-01' THEN o.Total ELSE 0 END) as JunToAugTotal,
    SUM(CASE WHEN o.OrderDate >= '2012-09-01' and o.OrderDate < '2012-11-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SepToOctOrders,
    SUM(CASE WHEN o.OrderDate >= '2012-09-01' and o.OrderDate < '2012-11-01' THEN o.Total ELSE 0 END) as SepToOctTotals,
    SUM(CASE WHEN o.OrderDate >= '2012-06-01' and o.OrderDate < '2012-11-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as JunToOctOrders,
    SUM(CASE WHEN o.OrderDate >= '2012-06-01' and o.OrderDate < '2012-11-01' THEN o.Total ELSE 0 END) as JunToOctTotals
From
    dbo.tblOrder o
Where
    o.DomainProjectID = 13
Group By
    o.BillEmail
Having
    SUM(CASE WHEN o.OrderDate >= '2012-06-01' and o.OrderDate < '2012-09-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
    SUM(CASE WHEN o.OrderDate >= '2012-09-01' and o.OrderDate < '2012-11-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
Order By
    o.BillEmail
```

Comment: This looks great and is way more than I was asking for. I'll have to look it over to wrap my head around it, haha /beginner

Comment: Glad it works for you and you're in good company here on Stack Overflow. We all started as beginners :)

Answer (score 1):

Would it be that bad to set up two queries?

Comment: I just didn't know the best way to do it and wanted advice. :c